# jQuery animations slow in webkit browsers

Tags: jquery, performance, webkit

I have just finished adding some animations to [my website](http://www.monkey-touch.com). I create some divs of trees, and let them pop up before letting the content show, and then the ipad. Furthermore, pressing the portfolio, shows a folder like the one you see on ipad. Pressing one of these 'apps', extends the ipad fully and detaches the content. The latter part works fine on all browsers, at least the latest versions. The popping up of the trees and the extending of the folder when pressing portfolio however is slow in Safari and Chrome (the webkit browsers). I can't really figure out why this is. Im pretty new to jQuery, so please excuse me if im being backwards.

The code for the slow animation

```
function portfolioToggle()
    {
        var animationTime = 500;
        var extendedHeight = 153;
        var appFolder = $('#menu #app_folder');
        if(appFolder.css('height') == '0px')
        {
            appFolder.animate({height : extendedHeight}, animationTime, 'swing');
        }
        else
        {
            appFolder.animate({height : 0}, animationTime, 'swing');
        }
    }
```

Thanks so much.

Comment: It is often useful to post the code that you believe is the culprit :)

Comment: Seems pretty snappy to me in Chrome 19, OSX

Comment: @AbstractChaos Yes you're right, I've added some code now. Its just that the animations are slow in general, so I was more guessing for some help from someone familiar with WebKit differences and/or WebKit jQuery performance guidelines.

Comment: @JonathanNicol Thanks for the feedback, that is interesting, so perhaps it's just the WebKit browsers for Windows? Any thoughts would be appreciated

Comment: Snappy in Gecko browsers too, Got it in FF13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `display:inline-block` out of `float:left`.
Floats slow down performance

Comment: Will give this a try, thank you for the feedback. I will get back to you.

Comment: Nope sorry, this doesn't work. Have removed all float lefts, even though some mess up the look when replaced by inline-block, the problem persists. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: Accepted, although it did not solve it, it is definitely good practice to do so, and might very well be the culprit for anyone stumbling upon this problem..